# .scrollTop() with conditional statement breaking on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

So I'm new to jQuery, I think I'm making some ground but I'm having problems with the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $header = $('#header');
    var $st = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log($st);

    if ($st < 250) {
        console.log($st);
        $header.height(300 - $st);
    } else {
        $header.hover(function(){
            $(this).height(300);
        }, function (){
            $(this).height(50);
        });
    }
}).scroll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4rsj/

So everything seems to be working okay, the 'header' scales down on scroll and expands and contracts on hover, however I've found a bug. It doesn't happen on page load, but once you scroll down the page and return to the top again the header (upon hover) sizes down to .height(50) even though from what I understand the hover should only be fired once scrollTop() is greater than 250.

I've logged the value of scrollTop() to make sure it's not a number that accumulates and have tried various different ways of doing this, but I can't get it to work / understand the problem. Eventually I'd like to animate the hover effects to be less janky, but that's for another day.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to fix this, but just so you understand the concept, when you attach the `hover` event listener to the `$header` after going beyond `$st < 250` it doesn't go away when you scroll back up. The hover listener and the associated functions stay attached to the `$header`, so regardless of where you are scrolling in the window the `hover` functions will still be active. One way to fix it is to include checks for the `scrollTop()` in the hover methods. Alternatively, you could try removing the `hover` listener when you scroll back up.

Comment: This was a great help, I now understand how the hover listener works - which happened to be my main source of confusion. Thanks for explaining that through to me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/J4rsj/2/)**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $header = $('#header');
    var $st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ($st < 250) {
        $header.height(300 - $st);
        $header.off(); // remove all events from #header
    } else {
        $header.on({ // on mouseenter & mouseleave, note: .on({hover: doesn't seem to work
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).height(300);
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).height(50);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Documentation for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

You can also use .off() with an event specified like so: `$header.off('mouseleave');` if you need to remove certain events and leave others intact.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me as well, I really appreciate the time you've taken out for this. It'll be really useful for me to know the .on() and .off() functions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You've both helped me problem solve my question. The goalposts changed in the process, so this is what I've ended up with.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var $header = $('#header');
    var $st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var $headerS = 300 - $st;

    $header.height($headerS);

    $header.hover(function(){

        $(this).stop().animate({height:300}, 300);

        }, function (){

        $(this).stop().animate({height:$headerS}, 600);

    });

}).scroll();
```

I've also set a min-height: 50px; for the #header element in the CSS. It seems to work fine and has this added benefit:

When $st is < 250px then hovering still expands the box to the total height and reduces back down to align with the top of the article. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/rufusdenne/J4rsj/3/